# Name of a manga about angels and devils marriage for peace

Tags: angel-diary

I am looking for a manga where there is an angel princess who ran away from home and crossdressed as a boy to disguise. There is another girl who helps the protagonist - that girl is not only an angel, but she is also a guardian warrior thing (4 of them). The crossdressing girl ran away from marriage with a devil for peace. Her best friend while running away is the brother of the devil, but she didn't know he was a devil.

When angel royalty turns sixteen, they need to choose their gender. When the crossdressing girl turns sixteen, she was an ice general, but she wanted to be a lazy prince like her brothers. She had to be girl for marriage since she is the only one left that hasn't chosen her gender.

Comment: [Hi user7911, don't forget to visit our **TOUR PAGE** to enhance your experience here ;)](http://anime.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Please check whether there is anything different from your intended meaning. I tried to make your post better, but I am not sure about the details.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for seems to be a manhwa(Korean comics) and all of what you described seems to be listed:

- cross dressing
- she is watched over by two of the Four Guardians of Heaven
- princess angel
- unwanted marriage
- Devils

---

## [Angel Diary (Manhwa)](http://myanimelist.net/manga/778/Angel_Diary)

[image: cover]

## Synopsis

> The only Angel Princess of Heaven is betrothed to the Emperor of the Underworld. Unable to accept her future with the Demon King, she realizes that her only choice is to run away. Her plan is to join the human world disguised as a schoolboy! Now all of the Gods from Heaven and Hell are searching high and low on the earth trying to make sure that a wedding happens.
>
> Source: MAL